# Why a muslim woman cannot get married to a non-muslim man while a muslim man is allowed to get married to a non-muslim?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, islamic-philosophy, non-muslim, islamic-basis

I am curious about why there is a restriction on women to not to get married with a non-muslim man while it is totally okay for a muslim man to get married to a non-muslim woman.

It is also quite interesting to see that a muslim woman is considered to abandon the religion if she gets married to a non-muslim while a man acquires merit in God's sight since he induced a person to convert to Islam.

Why these rules differ by gender? Or better asked: Why there is a need for such a rule to take place while every independent person can and should use their freewill to choose the person they want to get married to? Is not it also a psychological violence if a young woman is not supported in her decision by her close family members or pushed to leave her beloved one due to his beliefs?

I know there is no easy answer to this, but I see a lot of young women who feel conditioned to not to love any non-muslim due to the pressure by society. Especially for those who live abroad, it is extremely high chance that they will fall in love and get into a relationship with a non-muslim.

I would like to hear an opinion/explanation on this, why this is the case and should it still be.

Comment: The site is not for opinions or discussions.

Comment: you misunderstood it, neither men(except ahle-kitab under few conditions) nor women are allowed to get married until the other reverts to Islam sincerely.